# Unable to Login to my developer salesforce Org using Salesforce Authenticator App

Tags: salesforce1-app, app

I have setup a Salesforce Authenticator App and configured it for my org.
Everything was working perfect and I was able to login through the one time generated key from this app on my mobile, now "Salesforce Authenticator App" got crashed on my phone and it got disconnected from my org.

Now I cannot login to my account without entering a one time Key generated by the app.

There is no such way through which I can establish the connection again or can generate the same QR code to scan again. I am kind of stuck here.

Please help me out guys.

Comment: Please tell us you didn't do this for your primary login on a DE Org! If you set-up 2 factor authentication using a DE Org, you need to do it using a 2nd user's login, not for the primary login for exactly the reasons you've encountered.

Comment: Unfortunately I did it for the primary one :(

Comment: Is there anything through which i can recover my account

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. This is one of the things I recall the documentation cautioning against if one is using a DE. Perhaps someone else will have an idea or know of something you can do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can log a case with Salesforce from a different org, and hopefully they would be able to help you out in this scenario.